# Span (u,v) and the set S

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that says...

Let $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be fixed vectors throughout this exercise set. Let S be the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n $that are orthogonal to both u and v.

1) Find all vectors that are simultaneously in both S and span(u,v)?

2) Can you explicitly describe the set S $\cap$ span(u,v)?

I understand that a span is the set of all linear combinations of u and v and that for S to be orthogonal to u and v their dot product must equal zero, but I'm confused how I would use this information to help solve these.

My idea for an answer to question 1) is...

if u=0 then v can be anything

if v=0 then u can be anything

if v=u=0

Is this right or am I on the right track? If so, can I just write it like that?

As for question 2)...
would you just say that it's the set of all vectors that are orthogonal to both u and v? I don't feel like I'm understanding this question...

Comment: Let $w\in$ span$(u,v)$.  Then $w = a_1u+a_2v$ for some numbers $a_1,a_2$.  What happens when you take the dot product of $w$ and a vector that's in $S$?

Comment: Orthogonality implies linear independency but the opposite is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 and 2 are essentially the same thing, asking "what is the vector that is orthogonal to itself", or mathematically find $\vec v$ such that $<\vec v,\vec v>=0,$ where $<\dot{},\dot{}> $ is the inner product (dot product in this case).

Under this assumption $\vec v$ must be the zero vector.

And $\{\vec 0\}=\text{span}\{u,v\}\cap S$